# R/XML parsing: weird value

Tags: xml, r, parsing

For some reason sometimes the return value of `xmlToList` does not correspond to the input in an obvious way:

```
> library('XML')
> xmlToList(xmlTreeParse('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a type="List of Filter(s)">
  <b topic="foo" id="1">
    <c topic="bar" id="2">
      <d topic="baz" id="3">
      </d>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>'))
[[1]]
[1] "baz"

[[2]]
[1] "3"

[[3]]
topic    id 
"bar"   "2" 

[[4]]
topic    id 
"foo"   "1" 

$.attrs
               type 
"List of Filter(s)"
```

Where are my element names `a`..`d`?

Why does the data come in the reversed order?

Why is `d` treated differently from `b` and `c`?

> R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
>   Package: XML
>   Version: 3.98-1.1

Comment: using `xmlParse` instead of `xmlTreeParse` gives me a list with element names